# Consecration of the first born

Tags: genesis, luke, numbers

Numbers 3:11,12: ...I have taken the Levites from among the Israelites in place of the first male offspring of every Israelite woman.  The Levites are mine, for every firstborn are mine...

Why do we see in Luke 2:22 and 23 that Jesus is taken to the Temple in order to present him to the Lord according to the Law given in Exodus 13:2,12 about the first born being dedicated to God when we see in Numbers 3:11,12 that the Lord took the Levites in place of the first born?

Answer (score 2):

You can see by reading the entire Chapter 3 of Numbers, especially verse 7, that GOD chose the tribe of Levi to "do the service of the temple", rather than to assign first-born sons of all the tribes of Israel to do the service of the temple.

http://www.superbook.org/LAMSA/NUM/num3.htm

This does not mean that first-born sons were no longer dedicated to GOD, nor had any other way to serve GOD.

So to answer your question, because Jesus was a first-born son, he was dedicated to GOD, and his mission had nothing to do with the service of the temple, but rather to be a Prophet and a spiritual High Priest, at least at his first coming, and then a world ruling King at his second coming, and it was directly stated by the angel Gabriel to Mary that her son Jesus would be this prophesied son of David / King of Israel: "He will be great, and he will be called the Son of the Highest; and the Lord God will give him the throne of his father David. And he will rule over the house of Jacob for ever; and there will be no limit to his kingdom (Luke 1)."

I hope you feel this answers your question.